# Is it possible to insert a stream processor between 2 Kafka topics dynamically?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to Kafka and streams of data architecture and I have a question regarding the topics design and topology.

I have a flow that is really standard.

- An incoming stream of data measurements --> first topic T1
- Data sanitation (null values, high/low, transformations,
  formatting etc) --> second topic T2
- Data processing --> third topic T3
- Data persistance --> fourth topic T4
- Data sink --> into a TS-DB (InfluxDB for example)

What I want to do is be able to insert custom stream processors between these topics dynamically.

For example, add another parameter to the message after topic T2 and before T3. So I would create a topic T2.5 and re-route T2 to send to T2.5 and T2.5 to T3.

One way to do that is to update the T2 and T3 connectors and insert another one through Connect REST API. But for that, I would have to create a custom connector for every new requirement/case that I have.

Is there another way to do that?

I would also accept the answer that my topology/architecture is not the most optimal one for kafka topics, but please provide an example of the alternative that you suggest

Comment: I assume you are using Kafka Streams. Do you have one application for the whole pipeline? Or do you have multiple applications?

Comment: Kafka Connect isn't really "dynamic" in this way... Perhaps you'd get more value out of something like NiFi or Streamsets

Comment: @Matthias J. Sax I was thinking of having one application transition. ie one for T1->T2 one for T2->T3 etc. So this way I would have to stop the T1->T2 processor. Reroute it to send to topic T1.5 for example and then have T1.5->T2 processor read from that topic.

Comment: @cricket_007 I have looked into NiFi and indeed it statisfies the "dynamic stream change" requirement but it is not easy to do that using code. you need make multiple REST API calls (correct me if I'm wrong) in order to create the required changes programatically.

Comment: Using either tool, yes, you need API calls to manipulate the flows